# Open a window showing drive contents

Tags: cmd, command

Can anyone help me please? I want to open a window on a drive in windows 10 from either the command line or powershell for example I want to open an explorer window on drive E: so I can open a folder on E: in explorer. Using Visual Basic....which when I close the explorer window reverts back to the original command line.
Cheers

explorer.exe from cmd opens the windows pc showing all the drives, but I cannot get the syntax right to just open drive E:  - it just keeps saying "the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The path is E: the drive is named as Media

Comment: form command line: `start e:\ ` (or `start "" "E:\any folder\subfolder"`). Also `explorer.exe "e:\any folder"`

Answer (score 0):

simply: `explorer e:` from command line works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).